# Multiple if statements aren't working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, settimeout

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  I have a few else if statements but only the first one would fire.  I figured that was because they were all checking for the variable at the same time and then the function was over.  That's why I put it all in a setTimeout so that it would continuously call this function to check if the number had changed. how am i supposed to do this?

```
var slide=1;
    alert(slide);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (slide == 1){
                slide = '2';
                alert(slide);
                $('img.slidephoto').attr('src',"images/slide2.png");
            }
            else if (slide == 2){
                slide = '3';
                alert(slide);
                $('img.slidephoto').attr('src',"images/slide3.png");

            }
            }, 1000);
```

Comment: One problem is that the string '2' is not equal to the integer 2. When you set `slide = '2';`, that will not trigger `else if (slide == 2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to execute a function at regular interval, [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) execute the function only once

```
var slide = 1;
alert(slide);
setInterval(function () {
    if (slide == 1) {
        slide = '2';
        alert(slide);
        $('img.slidephoto').attr('src', "images/slide2.png");
    } else if (slide == 2) {
        slide = '3';
        alert(slide);
        $('img.slidephoto').attr('src', "images/slide3.png");

    }
}, 1000);
```

It can be written better using

```
var slide = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    slide++;
    $('img.slidephoto').attr('src', "images/slide" + slide + ".png");
    //reset the value to 1 on upper bound
    // ex: slide = slide > 3 ? 0: slide; if there are maximum of 3 images like slide1.png, slide2.pnd and slide3.png
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `slide = 3` never wins here.

Comment: Perfect. I had completely forgotten about setInterval. Thanks